# absolute img center position in div

Tags: html, css

How to center align img with absolute positioning in div or table cell if I dont know width of image?

for example

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <img style="position: absolute" />
</div>
```

Comment: Align to what? where?

Comment: edit my question: center and i dont know width

Comment: Could you apply it as a background image of the parent element?

Answer (score 7):

Aligns the element horizontal and vertical to the relative parent.

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <img class="centered" />
</div>

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

'top' and 'left' set to 50% will center the top-left-corner of the element. Translating is by -50% for both X and Y sets the element to the exact center of the parent.

For browser support take a look here:
[**Translate2d - caniuse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts It is centered in the parent element in your fiddle. You parent elements height is 0px. That's why it's placed -50% from top.

Comment: @KilianStinson Ah, sorry I see now. You were centering horizontally *and* vertically! Sorry, I shouldn't read SO and try to do work at the same time ;) Nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the negative margin trick, assumed you know the dimensions of the image:

```
img{
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   margin-left  : -(<imagewidth>/2)px;
   margin-height: -(<imageheight>/2)px;
}
```

when you only target browsers which support the [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) feature you could do:

```
img{
   top:  calc(50% - <imagewidth>/2px);
   left: calc(50% - <imageheight>/2px);
}
```

When the browser supports translation you can translate it -50% of the image-dimensions:

```
img{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

If none of that is possible, your last resort is altered markup and `display:table`:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <img />
  </div>
</div>

div{height:100%;width:100%;
   display:table;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;}
div>div{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[see Demo for latest case](http://jsfiddle.net/8ajQJ/7/)

Comment: @user2560165 seeing from another answer that you need to support IE8, perhaps take a look at my midified answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;    
}
```

Check this [JSFIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/8ajQJ/3/)

or

```
div {
position: relative;
text-aligm: center;
width:2000px;
}

img {
position: absolute;
}
```

Check this [**JSFIDDLE2**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ajQJ/4/)

Comment: updated my question - i dont know the width: without width margin: 0 auto; not working

Comment: @user2560165 have added `display: block` along with it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to center an image vertically

if you know the height of div. then you can do image as vertical align.

```
div{
    text-align:center;
    height:150px;
    line-height: 150px;
}

img{
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```